# How to optimize loading of images on web/mobile web when scrolling

Tags: image, performance, backbone.js, load, haml

I am now loading all the images via my template when the image loads

```
 //For example, I will just pass the image url into the tempate when the page renders
  %div{class: "img_container <%= answer.image_scale %> <%=answer.show_image%>"}
    <% if (media_con.standard_resolution) { %>
    %a.fancy{href: "<%= media_con.standard_resolution %>"}
      %img{src: "<%=media_con.standard_resolution%>"}
```

I realize that by doing this (esp if I am loading many images on the page), it causes inefficieny esp apparent on the mobile web.

How can I load images only when they are in view (scrolling), maybe just load a thumbnail image and load the actual image when the view with the image comes to view.

Any advice here is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of libraries to achieve this. I've personally used the [Lazy Load Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) for jQuery ([demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html)). Instead of setting `<img src>` property in the template, you should set a property called `data-original` to the url of the image:

```
%img{data-original: "<%=media_con.standard_resolution%>", src="placeholder.png"}
```

And on the client side code (perhaps in `Backbone.view.render`) you initialize the library:

```
$("img[data-original]").lazyload();
```